# Jenkinsfile library dynamic retrieval with perforce

Tags: jenkins, scm

It is well documented that a library can be dynamically retrieved with a git repo:

```
library identifier: 'test@master', retriever: modernSCM(
    [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
    remote: 'my_repo'
    ])
```

what would be the equivalent for retrieving a library with perforce rather than git?